# Hiding and other styling of textbox not working in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, html

I have added a textbox to SharePoint as part of my project(`<input id="Text1" class="textbox" style="" type="text" readonly />`). I need to show hide the text box based on certain condition. i am unable to do so based with below
document.getElementById("Text1").style.display = 'none';
or 
document.getElementById("Text1").style.display = 'block';

both are not working.

i have attempted to remove border and put an under line to the text box. But for some reason the below styling is not working with SharePoint.

outline: none;

Comment: Did you checked the id of your textbox in F12 Development Tools ? Did you add ClientIDMode="Static" to static to your textbox ?

Comment: Tried that the id is showing as Text1. if i add <input id="Text1" class="textbox" style="display : none" type="text" readonly /> i can see the textbox is not visible any more, but at the same time document.getElementById("Text1").style.display = 'block'; or none doesnt work when i reach document.getElementById("Text1").style and put a dot the intellisense does not show display for some reason.

Comment: i have added as advised <input id="Text1" class="textbox" style="" ClientIDMode="Static" type="text" readonly /> but still the same.

Comment: I thought that you work with asp.net textbox control anyway try this jquery code : $("input#Text1").hide(); normally it works if not check if the condition is realized or not.

Answer (score 0):

“document.getElementById("Text1").style.display = 'none'” should work fine. Where do you add the JS code? Directly in the page? Have you added script type="text/javascript"
tab? Make sure that your JS has been executed.

How about “border:none;”?